# how to fix cannot read property in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

so I'm working on existing code base and I'm trying make the mat-form filed to get TextData that written in mam-chart.model.ts file but some reason I'm getting this error " ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined' "

and the same thing for color " ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'color' of undefined' "

Any suggestion or help will be really apppreciated

design.ts

```
import { Chart, TextData, ChartData} from 'src/app/mam-chart/models';
export class ChartDesignComponent implements OnInit {
 chart: Chart;
 chartData: ChartData;
}
```

design.html

```
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Text</mat-label>
                <input matInput  [(ngModel)]="chartData.textData.text" />
            </mat-form-field >

            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Color(# + hex color code)</mat-label>
                <input matInput [(ngModel)]="chartData.textData.color"/>
            </mat-form-field >
```

mam-chart.model.ts

```
export class Chart {
    id: number;
    chartType: ChartType = ChartType.chart;
    version: number = 2;
    dataType: ChartDataType = ChartDataType.static;
    template: ChartTemplate;

    .........

}
export class TextCard extends Chart {
    public chartData: CardDataChart;

    constructor(json?: any) {
        super(json)
        if (json == null) {
            return;
        }
        this.chartData = new ChartData(json.chartData);
    }
}


export class TextData {
    public text:  string;
    public color:  string;
    public size: string;
    public sizePx: number;

    constructor(json?: any) {
        if (json == null) {
            this.text = "";
            this.color = "";
            this.size = "";
            this.sizePx = 20;
            return;
        }
       ......

export class ChartData {
    filteredData: FilteredData[];
    figures: Figure[];
    textData: TextData;
}
```

[image: div *ngIf="chartData"]

Comment: This usually happens because, the previous value is undefined. In this case, it's `textData`. Could you add the traceback of this error?

Comment: @ngShravil.py I'm not sure how to traceback since I got this error when I tried to add this [(ngModel)]="chartData.textData.text" in HTML. I uploaded a pic of the errors so can you take a look at it pls.. thank

Comment: Where are you initializing `chartData` in `design.ts` and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably because '`chartData`' is undefined initially on page load.
You might solve this error and get the appropriate result if you slightly modify the html to link the ngModel `chartData.textData.text` when chartData is actually present; or initialize chartData as an object of the required type.

Code :

```
       <div *ngIf="chartData && chartData.textData">
       <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Text</mat-label>
            <input matInput  [(ngModel)]="chartData.textData.text" />
        </mat-form-field >

        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Color(# + hex color code)</mat-label>
            <input matInput [(ngModel)]="chartData.textData.color"/>
        </mat-form-field >
        </div>
```

Now the  form field will only be visible when chartData Object has a key 'textData'

Comment: hi... I don't think I really get it so please can you help how to do that?.